# Reflection operator and plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reflection

Let $R:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ is reflection linear transformation on plane $\pi: x+2x+3z=0$:

a)Find a matrix of linear transformation $R$ using base $B=\{v1,v2,v3\}$ where $v_1=(1,1,-1), v_2=(-1,2,-1), v_3=(1,2,3)$

b)find a matrix of linear transformation using standard base of $R^3$

First I notice that $v_3$ is our normal vector so $v_1,v_2$ span the plane, and they orthogonal, then I know that $R(v_1)=v_1$, $R(v_2)=v_2$ and $R(v_3)=-v_3$, so I know how to do for that base, but I do not know how to do for standard base, I know for formula $Ref(v)=v-2\frac{v\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a$,here is just one vector a,but know I do not know is that formula for my case goes like this, if $qi=\frac{v_i}{||vi_||}$ ,$i=1,2$ now I put $Ref(e_1)=e_1-2\frac{e_1\cdot q_1}{q_1\cdot q_1}q_1-2\frac{e_1\cdot q_2}{q_2\cdot q_2}q2$, I put orthogonal vectors or orthonormal vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the matrix $[R]_B^B$ and the basis $B$, you may derive the change of basis matrices from the standard basis $S$ to $B$ and back, i.e. you may determine the representation matrices $[id]_S^B$ and $[id]_B^S$.

The former is easily determined as

$$[id]_S^B=\begin{pmatrix}[v_1]_S &[v_2]_S &[v_3]_S\end{pmatrix}$$

where $[v_i]_S$ is the column vector of the coordinatization of $v_i$ with respect to the standard basis, i.e.

$$[id]_S^B=\begin{pmatrix}[v_1]_S &[v_2]_S &[v_3]_S\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 &-1 &1\\1 &2 &2\\-1 &-1 &3\end{pmatrix}$$

For the latter, just note that $[id]_B^S={[id]_S^B}^{-1}$. Now, you have

$$[R]_S^S=[id]_S^B[R]_B^B[id]_B^S=[id]_S^B[R]_B^B{[id]_S^B}^{-1}$$

Comment: Yes i know for that formula, but I think that is similar when I doing orthogonal projection I can use orthonormal vector and with formula I just switch,

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić I'm not really sure about what you are trying to do. There might be a nicer approach for this particular example but nevertheless I think that considering this (general) way of expressing change of basis by matrix multiplication is in the case of changing to the standard basis particularly fast as you obtain one matrix almost for free.

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić You can certainly use a formula that you’ve memorized or derived for yourself to find the matrix of the reflection in the standard basis, but I strongly suspect that the point of this exercise is to get you to apply a change of basis to the matrix that you found in the first part.

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić Well, this whole concept of change of basis matrices, how they compose to provide change of basis for a matrix representation of a linear operator and how to derive matrix representation is pretty much mathematical folklore, so I did not actually use anything I've (sincerely) derived myself.

Comment: I get this matrix L=$\frac{1}{7}\begin{bmatrix}
                             6 & -2& -3\\
                              -2& 3& -6\\
                               -3& -6 &-2
                           \end{bmatrix}$
but  if I using base b1,b2,b2 I get reflection of that matrix, but if I use e1,e2,e3, i do not get reflection so it not matrix of standard base?